# Eject / Unmount USB Programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, usb, usb-otg

I am developing an Android Application in Xamarin where I listen to USB devices connected to my Android Device via OTG. I have been successful in listening to the USB devices connecting to my Android Device through BroadcastReceiver.

I am stuck on 2 places :

1. The moment I get to know that a device has been connected, I want to
   disconnect it programmatically. This is for security reasons.
2. Although I am able to detect the USB devices, the receiver seems to
   have gone Global. That is , even if my app is not running in the
   background and if I connect a USB device through OTG, the
   BroadcastReceiver listens to it. I don't want that to happen.

I searched a lot of sites but was not able to find any help regarding eject/unmounting programmatically.

This is what I have done so far :

```
   UsbDetection usbDetection;

    protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        usbDetection = new UsbDetection();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE");
        RegisterReceiver(usbDetection, filter);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]

[Android.App.IntentFilter(actions: new[] {"android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE",
"android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED",
"android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"})]

```
public class UsbDetection : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        string action = intent.Action;
        Console.WriteLine(action);
        Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, action, ToastLength.Long).Show();

        if(action.Equals("android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"))
        {
            UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(UsbManager.ExtraDevice);

            if(device!=null)
            {
                Programmatically eject/unmount the usb device. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions regarding this will be helpful.

Comment: If you only want to get the broadcast when your app is running, only use the runtime `RegisterReceiver` method to register (and unregister) and remove the attributes on your BroadcastReceiver (that become manifest entries) so the OS will not create/invoke your broadcast receiver when your app is not running

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks. Done with the 2nd issue. Still working on the 1st.

Comment: I do not think a "user app" can eject/`unmount` a file system, (usb drive or sdcard) unless you have root access. If you have a system signed app you could of course. There were some old hacks/workarounds, but I doubt these work in any recent API version as they were security and stability flaws, follow the link for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39792785/4984832

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for the link, will check if it works. Still working on it. Will post If I come up with something or if I find a workaround.