# What's the handle of Service generated by AIDL?

Tags: android, android-source, aidl, android-binder

It's known to us that android system service register to system manager when  device is booting.For Example:

```
        AlarmManagerService alarm = new AlarmManagerService(context);
        ServiceManager.addService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE, alarm);
```

The code above is in

> /frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java

So,if you want to use AlarmManager you, you only need to get the proxy of AlarmManagerService to call a function, and then **AlarmManagerProxy** call the corresponding method in BinderProxy to execute.

Importantly, the BinderProxy.java or BpBinder.cpp  has the right handle to Binder---AlarmManagerService.

But when comes to AIDL, for example:

```
   interface IDCSCore {
      int add(int i,int j);
      void show();
   }
```

When we bind a remote service in another process, the onBind method will return a Binder--the implemention of IDCSCore.Stub, then in the ServiceConnect onServiceBinded call back you get the IDCSCore.Stub.Proxy.
Android System Service,such as AlarmManagerSerice is register in servicemanger, and you can use `adb shell service list` to find all system service in system manager, but I can't find the IDCSCore related infomation. Where is the IDCSCore.Stub? How the proxy without handle correctly execute a function call??

I am frustrated! It is a bit sophiscated to me...

Comment: Are you trying to add a custom system service ? What is IDCSCore ? See this example: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**AOSP system service** and **Android service** both have different implementation and works differently. You can't bind to the AOSP system services. In order to get the proxy stub, AOSP has already provided the `getSystemService()` API. ServiceManager holds all the proxy stub of system services.

To list all activity services, below command can be used.

```
adb shell dumpsys activity services
```

What is IDCSCore?

To get more details on AOSP system service and Android service refer this link,
[AOSP System Service vs Service Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179832/aosp-system-service-vs-service-differences)