# Can not find method reportLocation() from "android.location.ILocationManager" in Android Q

Tags: java, android, reflection, location, android-binder

> I am trying to get method reportLocation() through reflection from
>   "android.location.ILocationManager$Stub".

CODE:

```
 Class<?> mStub = Class.forName("android.location.ILocationManager$Stub");
 Method getInterface = mStub.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);

 Class mServiceManager = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
 Method getService = mServiceManager.getMethod("getService", String.class);

 Object iBindermInterface = getService.invoke(null, "location");
 Object mInterface = getInterface.invoke(null, (IBinder) iBindermInterface);

 Method method = mInterface.getClass().getMethod("reportLocation", Location.class, Boolean.class);
```

ERROR:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.reportLocation [class android.location.Location, class java.lang.Boolean]
```

I do not see this method when I trying to print all methods from "android.location.ILocationManager$Stub":

```
 Class<?> mStub = Class.forName("android.location.ILocationManager$Stub");
  Method[] getInterfaceAll = mStub.getMethods();
        for (Method getInt : getInterfaceAll)
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "getInt = "+getInt);
```

In Android P (SDK 28) I have no problem with it.

In Android Q (SDK 29) interface `android.location.ILocationManager` does not have `reportLocation()` method, instead, to my assumptions, interface `com.android.internal.location.ILocationProviderManager` has `onReportLocation()`. But this interface contains the abstract method `onReportLocation()` and I cannot get its implementation.

> What interface contain this method or it has been changed (renamed) to
>   another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to put location on report.

Use the public boolean injectLocation(@NonNull Location newLocation) method, it can be obtained from ILocationManager.

```
        Class<?> mStub = Class.forName("android.location.ILocationManager$Stub");
        Method getInterface = mStub.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
        Method getService = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager")
            .getMethod("getService", String.class);
        Object mInterface = getInterface
            .invoke(null, (IBinder) getService.invoke(null, "location"));
        Method method = mInterface.getClass()
            .getMethod("injectLocation", Location.class);
        method.invoke(mInterface, location);
```

Comment: This seems to be blocked now in Android 10. Is there any alternative?

Comment: it works on Android 10 and 11, but I did not mentioned that it works with the system apps. If you interested in It looks like  android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" need to add in AndroidManifest.xml and so on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222535/create-system-application

Comment: Thanks for the info! Are you using compileSdkVersion 29 or 30?

Comment: I am getting this error on Android 10: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.injectLocation [class android.location.Location]

Can you please explain why android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" is needed and how does that change anything? My app is already a system app. Also would Google Play Store maybe complain if you add that in the manifest? Thanks!

Comment: So basically it is not allowed to use it: Accessing hidden method Landroid/location/ILocationManager;->injectLocation(Landroid/location/Location;)Z (greylist-max-o, reflection, denied)

Answer (score 0):

This is the life of using internals API with reflection.

The problem it's simple, the `reportLocation(in Location location, boolean passive)` method was present until Android 9 in the `ILocationManager.aidl` interface, check [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/pie-release/location/java/android/location/ILocationManager.aidl#113)

But starting from Android 10 the method has been removed as you can see in the internal section [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/location/java/android/location/ILocationManager.aidl#116)

> You should probably change your code to use some public APIs, or you
>   will have hard time scanning the current APIs and find a replacement
>   to use with reflection. (and you will still risking they blacklisting
>   the API in the future)

PS: Just for complete information, probably the functionality has been moved [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android10-release/location/lib/java/com/android/location/provider/LocationProviderBase.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F#200) (I've followed some commits, but this could be completely unusable/different and I really discourage you to try to use it)

Comment: Any idea how to call that function now from LocationProviderBase? Thanks!

Or better to just call ILocationProviderManager.onReportLocation?