# Forget stored WiFi networks programmatically

Tags: xamarin.android

What is the way to forget the old Wi-Fi network saved and delete connection file in android 6 and higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to forget the old wifi network saved , you can follow bellow ways to have a try :

```
public void RemoveWiFi()
{
    WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager)GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
    WifiConfiguration mWifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    List<WifiConfiguration> conlist = (List<WifiConfiguration>)mWifiManager.ConfiguredNetworks;//获取保存的配置信息
    for (int i = 0; i < conlist.Count; i++)
    {
        Log.Debug("Tag", "i = " + i + "SSID = " + conlist[i].Ssid + " netId = " + conlist[i].NetworkId);
        
        // Forget the specified wifi 
        // if (conlist[i].Ssid == "xxx") { ... }
         
        // Forget the current connected wifi
        if ( i == 0 ) 
        {
            mWifiManager.RemoveNetwork(conlist[i].NetworkId);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Not forget to add permissions in **AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

**Note** :

*You need to turn the app into a system app and give system permissions .*

1. Modify the `AndroidManifest.xml` :

...

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package=xxxx"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
    coreApp="true">

 <application
        android:process="system"
 />
```

2. Install app bellow `/system/app` folder in Android device .

Comment: hi Junior Jiang .When placing the code inside the button and pressing the application stops
Note that I gave the permission

Comment: @ALIE Okey ,could you share the error logs here ? And whehter test it in a physical device .

Comment: @ALIE Hi , sorry for noting that . This method needs to turn the app into a system app and give system permissions .

Comment: I used the following method after placing the void  buttona.Click += delegate
            {
                RemoveWiFi();
            };

Comment: @ALIE I have updated answer , also need the system permission . Because from Android 6.0 , not allows private app to remove wifi configuration.

Comment: I will try the code on the phone after the amendment and talk back to you

Comment: Could you please help me by raising an example of github

Comment: @ALIE Sorry for can not showing with github , because it nees ROOT in Android Device . About System application , refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222535/create-system-application